# Info.plist and CFBundleDisplayName in document packages/bundles

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bundle, info.plist

Is `Info.plist` fully supported in document packages/bundles? Documentation make it seems like it is but I couldn't find specific mentions on this topic. I want to use `CFBundleDisplayName` to show a localized name of a document to the user, but for some reason it doesn't affect the visible name of the package in Finder.

`NSBundle` correclty loads and reads Info.plist keys, but Finder ignores `CFBundleDisplayName` key (although properly shows some others such as `CFBundleShortVersionString`).

Comment: have you tried the `localizedInfoDictionary` method on the bundle?

Comment: @BradAllred I did. NSBundle reads those parameters correctly, but Finder still displays the basic name, it doesn't want to show what I specified in CFBundleDisplayName. Please see edited question.